# How to zoom PDF file and take a screenshot of zoomed area in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, zooming, pinchzoom

I want to zoom PDF file much much more and take a screenshot of zoomed area. I tried with **RepaintBoundary** and **InteractiveViewer** but with InteractiveViewer image (PDF) not zoomed with double tap as well pinch to zoom not work properly.

My Code

```
FutureBuilder<List<im.Image>>(
          future: imageFromPdfFileFullImage(PdfDocument.openFile(pdfPath)),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return RepaintBoundary(
              key: globalKey,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final pdfImage = snapshot.data[index];
                  MemoryImage img = MemoryImage(im.encodePng(pdfImage));
                  final Image image = Image.memory(
                    img.bytes,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  );
                  return InteractiveViewer(
                    panEnabled: true,
                    onInteractionStart: (value) {},
                    boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(80),
                    minScale: 0.5,
                    maxScale: 4,
                    //constrained: false,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      child: image,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          })

Future<List<im.Image>> imageFromPdfFileFullImage(
      Future<PdfDocument> pdfFile) async {
    final List<im.Image> imageList = List();
    int height = 0, width = 0;

    final document = await pdfFile;
    im.Image imImage;
    for (int i = 1; i <= document.pagesCount; i++) {
      final page = await document.getPage(i);
      final pdfPageImage = await page.render(
          width: page.width, height: page.height, format: PdfPageFormat.PNG);
      imImage = im.decodePng(pdfPageImage.bytes);
      height += imImage.height;
      // the width should correspond to the maximum
      // width of the image: it should not exceed it
      if (imImage.width > width) {
        width = imImage.width;
      }
      imageList.add(imImage);

      await page.close();
    }
    return imageList;
  }
```

I also used some other plugins like [flutter_fullpdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fullpdfview) and [interactiveviewer_gallery](https://pub.dev/packages/interactiveviewer_gallery) but does not meet my expectations.

If anyone have a idea how it will be work please help me.